# How do you get the rating data using the default rating button in Android?

Tags: android

I'm using the rating button with the id `@+id/ratingBar`. I want to get the data to see if the user clicks on one star, two stars, one and a half stars, etc. How do I get that data? I made an onClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getRating()` method.

It returns the number of stars that the user inputted as a float.

Answer (score 0):

If you would read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html), you can see you use `getRating()`.